# Swift apparently nil != nil?

Tags: swift

Someone please explain this to me. When I set a breakpoint and test the variable `d["status"]` then it prints out nil. But when I run it through an `if` statement. Then apparently it's not nil.

[image: Screenshot of my issue]

Comment: what is the actual data type of data in d["status"]

Comment: What is they type of value that you're expecting from d["status"] ?

Comment: I am not an expert here, but I think instead of checking

if d["status"] != nil{},

you could use 

if let temp == d["status"]{
    "you wont have a nil value here"
} else {
    "handle nil here"
}

Comment: I think the data type was AnyObject? . Which apparently didn't register as null. I casted it to a string: `let a = d["status"] as? String` and then tested a for null, and that worked.